# Почему при сабмите формы меняется uri

Tags: php, url

Я захожу на `http://site.loc/client/login/`
Структурно в этой директории лежит лишь index.php.
На странице есть форма. Когда кликаешь на сабмит формы, открывается `http://site.loc/client/login/index.php`

Как сделать так, чтобы uri всегда был как в первом случае?  И почему так происходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятнее всего, в `action` формы указано `index.php`. Вот на него и идет переход. Оставьте `action` пустым, или "/"

Comment: Точно, спасибо, совсем и забыл, что там указывал index.php

Comment: Пустой `action` запрещён стандартом HTML5 и невалиден, для сохранения текущего URL стандарт предписывает не указывать `action` вообще

Comment: @andreymal, именно это и имел в виду. Неправильно выразился - спасибо за уточнение